# How to find the amount of Mylan revenue generated for doxycycline hyclate drug

Tags: finance, drugs

I'm writing an article on the [antitrust investigation](http://www.nytimes.com/2016/12/15/business/generic-drug-price-lawsuit-teva-mylan.html?_r=0) into Mylan and other companies. I need to obtain the amount of annual revenue that Mylan generated from sales of the drug doxycycline hyclate 150mg for 2013 - 2016. Tried looking on the internet, but can't seem to find anything.

I might be able to estimate it by multiplying the number of prescriptions times the unit cost times the average number of pills per prescription sold for those years, but can't seem to find the number of prescriptions sold either.

Anyone have any ideas?